# Image Search API like Google Images search API

Tags: ios, api, google-image-search

I am trying to develop an Image Search like app. Currently I am using following Google Image Search API https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/services/search/images?v=1.0&q=taj
But it gives 4 images at a time. I am looking for same API which returns at least 15 images and after requesting will search for next page.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use "rsz" parameter to the above URL so that you can get the required size response. Your API becomes "https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/services/search/images?v=1.0&q=taj&rsz=8".
"rsz" parameter accepts only value between 1-8.

Comment: But now it seems Google removed the API... :(

Comment: @Sudhan this [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34043140/search-images-from-google-with-new-google-api-ios) may help you.